Ask mathematica to know if a solution to a system of polynomial equations (of order $2$ or $4$) exists (I don't need to actually find the solutions)
I have a system of 16 polynomial equations of degrees either 2 or 4 with 16 variables.
Mathematica struggles to find the solutions. I am only interested in knowing if a solution exists, but not really to find it.
Is there a simple way to ask mathematica this?
I know that there is the GroebnerBasis function that can do this, but in simpler examples I realized it took more time to compute this function than to give me the solutions with Solve. Hence, I suspect there might have more efficient methods than using GroebnerBasis. If so, I would like to know which.

This WFR function might work. Depends on the system, really. Why not post it?

You may calculate the length of the Groebner Basis to see if a solution exists. If the Groebner Basis has the same length as the number of variables, then a solution exists. If it is shorter, then there are either infinit many solutions or none.
Let us first define 16 random equations:
SeedRandom[1];
n = 16;
eq = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {n, n + 1}] . (var = 
     Table[x^i, {i, 0, n}]);
eq = Thread[eq == 0];

Now, the Groebner Basis of this has length:
GroebnerBasis[eq, Rest@var] // Length

16

If we now set the first equation equal to the second one, we have an underdetermined system:
eq[[1]] = eq[[2]]
GroebnerBasis[eq, Rest@var] // Length

15

If we now in addition set equation 1 to 1 instead if 0, we have an incompatible system:
eq[[1, -1]] = 1;
GroebnerBasis[eq, Rest@var] // Length

{1}

